# Can't pass parameter id in actionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can't understand where the problem... My rout values is :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And i try to pass parameter id :

```
@Html.ActionLink(app.Name, "SingleAppEdit", "Admin", new { id = app.Id }, null)
```

To my action in Controller "Admin":

```
public ActionResult SingleAppEdit(string appId)
        {
            var positions = new List<SelectListItem>
                                       {
                                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Top", Value = "Top"},
                                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Bottom", Value = "Bottom"},
                                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "None", Value = "None"}
                                       };
            ViewData["PositionsList"] = new SelectList(positions, "Value", "Text");


            var app = Apps.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == Convert.ToInt32(appId));
            return View(app);
        }
```

I get null in controller. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method parameter name is `appId`. But you are trying to pass a parameter named `id`.

**Solution** : Change your parameter name to match with the method definition.

```
@Html.ActionLink(app.Name, "SingleAppEdit", "Admin",
                                new { appId= app.Id }, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change appID in controller to just ID like this:

```
public ActionResult SingleAppEdit(string id)
        {
            var positions = new List<SelectListItem>
                                       {
                                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Top", Value = "Top"},
                                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Bottom", Value = "Bottom"},
                                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "None", Value = "None"}
                                       };
            ViewData["PositionsList"] = new SelectList(positions, "Value", "Text");


            var app = Apps.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == Convert.ToInt32(id));
            return View(app);
        }
```